# Marks should not be zero in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a table where student has to enter subject name and marks. i have make input box only for numeric only by javascript but i am not able to do validation so that student can not enter 0 as marks.

```js
$("#insertbotheli13").click(function () {
     $("#tablebotheli13").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {    
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablebotheli13" class="table table-striped table-hover">
         <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insertbotheli13"></input>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
  <th> Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control subject1" name="subject1">
            </td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control marks1 allownumericwithoutdecimal" name="marks1">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use `<input type="number" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the input value if it equal to zero then remove it, check the snippet below.

Also the events should be attached with the event delegation since you're adding the input's dynamically :

```
$("body").on("keypress keyup blur paste", ".allownumericwithoutdecimal", function(event) {
    if( $(this).val() == "0"){
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/0/g, "") );
    }

    if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#insertbotheli13").click(function() {
  $("#tablebotheli13").each(function() {
    var tds = '<tr>';
    jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {
      tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    });
    tds += '</tr>';
    if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
      $('tbody', this).append(tds);
    } else {
      $(this).append(tds);
    }
  });
});

$("body").on("keypress keyup blur paste", ".allownumericwithoutdecimal", function(event) {
  if( $(this).val() == "0"){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/0/g, "") );
  }

  if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablebotheli13" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insertbotheli13"></input>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control subject1" name="subject1">
      </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control marks1 allownumericwithoutdecimal" name="marks1">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Number(form.qty.value) > 0) {
    // Only executes if value is a positive number.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put a condition on `keyup` and remove `keypress` event as there is no need of now

```js
$("#insertbotheli13").click(function () {
     $("#tablebotheli13").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keyup blur",function (event) {  
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) <= 0) alert("Marks should be more than Zero");
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablebotheli13" class="table table-striped table-hover">
         <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insertbotheli13"></input>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
  <th> Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control subject1" name="subject1">
            </td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control marks1 allownumericwithoutdecimal" name="marks1">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

your javascript  call  a class `allownumericwithoutdecimal`.If u modify the class you will get the answer.
Your code was:

```
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keyup blur",function (event) {  
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) <= 0) alert("Marks should be more than Zero");
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

And Replace with this code:

```
 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").keypress(function(event)  {  

                if (!event.which || (49 <= event.which && event.which <= 57) || (48 == event.which && $(this).val())) {
                   /* */
               } else {
                   event.preventDefault();
               }
            });
```

It is worked for me.

> NOTE:Also you should try to delete `</input>` closing tag from your html.